# Infragistics And Intersoft Webcombo.NET 3.0

Tags: infragistics, webcombo

Facing design issues in my application, I have installed Infragistics NetAdvantage 2006 Vol 1 and Intersoft Webcombo.NET 3.0 SP3 Build 18 in my system, if I run the application getting design issues.

**Example:** I couldn't navigate into the tab.Currently I am using.NET 3.5 framework. Do I need to install any other later versions?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the reason that you are having issues at design time is because there is an exception thrown in the designer for one of the controls though it would be best if you expanded on your question to include more details if this isn't the case.

For your specific question, do you want to install any later versions, that is up to you.

For resolving the design time issue, if it is caused by the Infragistics controls make sure that you have the exact version installed that you are using in the project so that the design assemblies are in your GAC.  It is important that you have the correct service release installed.  Also there are known issues using the .NET 1.x controls in .NET 2.0 or later at design time so you will want to make sure you are using the .NET 2.0 controls unless you are using Visual Studio 2003.

Please note that NetAdvantage 2006 Volume 1 has been retired since the spring of 2009 and wasn't tested with any version of Visual Studio later than 2005.  The WebCombo was also retired in 2011 and was only ever supported in IE and Firefox when it was supporter.  This control isn't expected to work in any modern browser and you should upgrade your application.